# Counter of comparisons insertion sort

Tags: python, algorithm, comparison, insertion-sort

```
quick_sort_median(array[:], 0, n-1, 0)
```

I'm working on a quick sort and I'm passing it the following arguments. When my array dimension is less than 3, I call insertion sort. And it seems to me that I am incorrectly counting the comparisons. Here is my function

```
def insertion_sort(array, p, r, count):
    for i in range(p+1, r+1):
        key = array[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j >= p and array[j] > key:
            if(array[j-1] > array[j]): count += 1
            j -= 1
        array[j-1], array[j] = array[j], array[j-1]
        array[j+1] = key
        count += 1
    return array, count
```

I would appreciate your help or approval.

I tried to put the counters in different places

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should know that `array[:]` copies your array instead of passing it by reference, which may not be your intention

Comment: Would you please provide the examples which doesn't work as you wish?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi The thing is, I have a lot of functions and I wouldn't want to clutter my question with code. The number of comparisons everywhere does not match what was shown to me. So I'm trying to understand if I think it's correct in this function

Comment: @PoneyUHC Yes, that is right. Thanks friend, I'll think about optimization

Comment: Please demonstrate what the problem is.

Comment: What comparisons do you want to count?

Comment: BTW: The condition `(array[j-1] > array[j])` serves no purpose in your algorithm, and it even can reference an index that is less than `p`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Currently you are counting how many times `array[j-1] > array[j]` is evaluated **and** it is true. It doesn't count when it is false, yet it should.
- This comparison `array[j-1] > array[j]` does not contribute to the algorithm.
- This comparison `array[j-1] > array[j]` may reference an index that is less than `p`, which (when `p` is 0) could even trigger an error.
- The algorithm performs as many swaps as there are elements in the (sub)list. This is wrong. Instead insertion sort should *rotate* the value into its right spot.
- The list is sorted in-place so it should not have to return the list.
- The call `quick_sort_median(array[:], 0, n-1, 0)` will **copy** the list, which is counter productive. Both quick sort and insertion sort are supposed to do an in-place sort, so there should be no need to ever copy a list.

Here is a possible correction of `insertion_sort` with proper counting of the data comparisons:

```
def insertion_sort(array, p, r, count):
    for i in range(p+1, r+1):
        key = array[i]
        # Walk backwards in the sorted partition
        for j in range(i, p, -1):
            count += 1
            if key >= array[j - 1]:
                break
            array[j] = array[j - 1]  # move value to the right
        else:
            j = p
        # place key in the sorted partition
        array[j] = key
    return count
```

The call of `insertion_sort` should not do `[:]`, but pass the list as-is.